# Trigger Outlook Mail Body using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In VBA scripting ,I am trying to write a Sub Function which has the following signature

```
Sub(taskName As String , myGroup As String, myFile As String ,myPer As String, RelatedTasks() As String    )

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim m As Outlook.MailItem

 Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set m = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With m
   .display
   .To = "somewhere@someplace.com"
   .Subject = "Test Events"
   .HTMLBody/.body = ...    
End Sub
```

Email Body is as follows:

Hello All,

Please find the following information.

**TASK**: taskName

**RELATED TASK**:RelatedTasks()

**FILE** : myFile

**PERSON** : myPer

In the Sub function , the pattern to the left of colon is always constant.And the right side will change based on the inputs to the function.

For that I am reading the Template.htm which contains the required signature.

Template.htm contains:

```
Hello All,

Please find the following information.

TASK: {{mytask}}

RELATED TASK:{{myRelatedTasks}}

FILE : {{myFile}}

PERSON : {{myPerson}}
```

In VBA code,I am replacing all the fields.

The issue that I am facing is {{mytask}} and {{related tasks}} also should have a HTML reference. I have succeeded in adding the link to mytask .Clicking on the mytask in the mail will jump to the respective weblink.

```
<a href = "www.something.com&amp;id ={{taskID}}>
{{mytask}}.....<a href = "www.xxx.com&amp;id={{}}>{{myRelatedTasks}}
```

but having trouble in adding the same to Related tasks since it is an array.

My VBA code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateNewMail()

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim m As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim sigPath As String, sigText As String
 Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

 Dim t As String
 Dim r(5) As Variant

 t = "233444:dshfjhdjfdhjfhjdhfjdhfjd"


 r(0) = "122343:dsjdhfjhfjdh"
 r(1) = "323243:jfjfghfjhjddj"
 r(2) = "834783:gffghjkjkgjkj"

 Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set m = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 sigPath = "C:\Users\Pavan-Kumar\Desktop\vbs\TestEvents.htm"

 Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(sigPath)

 sigText = ts.ReadAll

 ts.Close

 Set fso = Nothing

 sigText = Replace(sigText, "{{mytask}}", t)
 sigText = Replace(sigText, "{{myRelatedTasks}}", Join(r, "<br>"))

 With m
   .display
   .To = "somewhere@someplace.com"
   .Subject = "Test Events"
   .HTMLBody = sigText

 End With 
End Sub
```

And also when I am joining the related tasks , I want them to come one below another with indentation. I tried it with giving "\t" as the delimiter with no success.

I want to give references to my Related tasks and also want them to neatly align them. Thanks.

This is what I am able to print in my outlook mail:

```
Hello All,
Please find the following information.
TASK: 233444:dshfjhdjfdhjfhjdhfjdhfjd
RELATED TASK:122343:dsjdhfjhfjdh
"\t"323243:jfjfghfjhjddj
"\t"834783:gffghjkjkgjkj
"\t"
"\t"
"\t"
 FILE : TImers
PERSON : Charvaka
```

Comment: If you want to pull from an array and add to a string, one option is to use a `For` loop from `LBound(array)` to `UBound(array), and process each row one-at-a-time

Comment: @Chronocidal But the main thing is , how can I change the  Template.htm file , for task <a href = "www.something.com&amp;id ={{taskID}}> , I am appending the taskID , how to do the same thing I am not able to do it for RelatedTasks since it is an array, there I cant use LBound keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Alignments:  You can either drop the Related Tasks into a Table, or you can use a Tab (`vbTab`, not `"\t"`)

For the multiple-rows:  This would be simpler if you had a 2D Array (e.g. `r(0,0)="RelatedTaskName"` and `r(0,1)="RelatedTaskID"`) instead of splitting it based on a Colon, but it's doable, and there are several different ways to go about it.

The method that I am going to use here is to build all of your string at once, then use Replace to dump the finished product:  (using Tab instead of a Table for the indents)

```
Dim taskID As String, taskName As String, lTaskNum As Long, TaskList As String
TaskList = "" 'Start with an empty list
For lTaskNum = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
    If Len(TaskList) > 0 Then TaskList = TaskList & vbTab 'We are using Tab instead of a table here
    taskName= r(lTaskNum) 'Grab element from the array
    taskID = Left(taskName, InStr(taskName, ":") - 1) 'Just the number
    taskName = Replace(taskName, taskID & ":", "",count:=1) 'Just the Link text
    TaskList = TaskList & "<a href = ""www.xxx.com&amp;id=" & taskID & """>" & taskName & "</a><br />" 'Add the task to the stack
Next lTaskNum
'If Len(TaskList) < 1 Then TaskList = "No Related Tasks" 'Optional bonus!
sigText = Replace(sigText, "{{myRelatedTasks}}", TaskList) 'Push the finished list into the email
```

Comment: It worked .Thanks for taking out your time and answering the question.I have one question though , that "vbTab" is not working , in the mail , it is still not getting indented.It is getting printed directly below the Related tasks header , I wanted some left indentation on that

Comment: Hmm...  You could try replacing `vbTab` with `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"` to add 4 non-breaking spaces instead?  Tab position may depend on where the tab-markers on the Horizontal Ruler are.  (This is why a [Table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) with an invisible border might be a better choice to keep everything in line)

Comment: Hi , I tried that too , still its  not happening ,  I tried it with Chr(9) keyword also

Comment: I did some testing:  I can get it to work with Non-breaking spaces, but you need about 32 of them to get it to "line up" properly.  You may want to just add the line `sigText = Replace(sigText, "RELATED TASK:{{myRelatedTasks}}", "<table><tr style=""vertical-align:top""><td>RELATED TASK:</td><td>{{myRelatedTasks}}</td></tr></table>")` to dump that section into a 1-row/2-column table for formatting purposes

Comment: I added the line , still no change , I added it before pushing the finished list into the email , is there a way to change my htm file , I tried adding margin left in the html but not getting the intended results

Comment: Hey buddy , it worked , I added what you men. tioned , in my htm file , somehow it did not work in vba  .thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: One more question:) , when I add the left margin , the reference underline will not start from the first letter instead immediately after colon: , how to avoid this